# Is self-expression not unique to creatives?

Tags: psychology, aesthetics

Often it's thought that "self-expression" is only possible in creative work and e.g. for this reason the pol. ideology communism as well as Maslow's hierarchy of needs thinks of the creative pursuits as the highest pursuits of the man.

But I've heard arguments arguing the opposite, that people express themselves through different sorts of activities and "self-expression" is not unique to the arts.

So which way is it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the question posed by Duchamps infamous/famous [object d'art](http://www.tate.org.uk/art/artworks/duchamp-fountain-t07573) that he submitted to an open exhibition that then refused to exhibit it; which under some readings, asked the question - what is art?

Before one is a writer, or an artist; one is a human being with an aspiration to write or paint.

The two situations that you suggest are not mutually exclusive or disjoint but touch each other at many points; and in fact, are grounded in each other.

Answer (score 1):

Maslow's self-actuaization (what you're calling self-expression) isn't necessarily related to creativity in the strict sense of the word.

The guitarist begging for money under the subway tunnel hasn't fulfilled most of the lower needs in the hierarchy, and yet is still doing creative work in the strict sense of the term.

Conversely, someone can be doing something very menial and non-creative, like driving a taxi or operating a forklift, and not have a single artistic/creative bone in his body, yet he is "at the top of the hierarchy", experiencing self-actuliztion because of a rich family and community life, and having already achieved all of the other needs in the hierarchy.

That being said, it is true that in our current economic system, those who get to use creativity and self-expression in their daily work (or more generally those whose skill set can't be commodified) tend to have already obtained the lower needs in Maslow's hierarchy, and are working on achieving the higher objectives.

I don't know where exactly did you get the notion that Marxist ideology holds creative pursuits "as the highest pursuits of the man" ? This seems to fly directly in the face of of Marx's other popular statement "From each according to his ability, to each according to his needs".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communist_society "Karl Marx considered "true richness" to be the amount of time one has at his or her disposal to pursue one's creative passions" and I've heard many claim that this is also the objective of a communist society, the freeing of time for creative pursuits.

Comment: Makes sense. It should be noted that creative pursuits as leisure should be differentiated from creative pursuits as an occupation. But the creative passions that you mention are different from Maslow's self actualization then, and are closer to pure artistic creativity.

Comment: I'm actually thinking that e.g. physicists may be an easy example of self-actualization in non-arts. It takes such involvement to be a physicist that I'd expect physicists to be "self-actualizing", otherwise they'd never have the energy to spend that much time on educating themselves. This reasoning may be extended to many  professions. If they've got the energy to perform the work, then it must be how they self-actualize? Self-actualization may not need to have anything mysterious to it, merely that it's a sense of fulfilling one's mission, doing what one thinks one ought to do.

Comment: Physics maybe not be an art, but it still involves a lot of creativity.